# How to add 2 listboxes to 1 window using Visual Studio C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, listbox

I have this code that works for 1 listbox but adding another one right below the first one is problematic. This is C code that works fine in C++. Also, duplicating the hwndList just erases the first listbox.

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "environ.h"

#define ID_LIST 1
#define ID_TEXT 2

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("Environ");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Environment List Box"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

fills the content of the listbox

```
void FillListBox(HWND hwndList)
{
    int iLength;

    TCHAR* pVarBlock, * pVarBeg, * pVarEnd, * pVarName;

    TCHAR* pVarBlockCopy = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
    pVarBlock = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
    while (*pVarBlock)
    {
        if (*pVarBlock != '=') // Skip variable names beginning with `=`
        {
            pVarBeg = pVarBlock; // Beginning of variable name
                while (*pVarBlock++ != '='); // Scan until `=`
            pVarEnd = pVarBlock - 1; // Points to `=` sign
            iLength = pVarEnd - pVarBeg; // Length of variable name
            // Allocate memory for the variable name and terminating
            // zero. Copy the variable name and append a zero.
            pVarName = (TCHAR*)(calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            CopyMemory(pVarName, pVarBeg, iLength * sizeof(TCHAR));
            pVarName[iLength] = '\0' ;
                // Put the variable name in the list box and free memory.
                SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            free(pVarName);
        }
        while (*pVarBlock++ != '\0') ; // Scan until terminating zero
    }
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlockCopy);
}
```

This section of the code seems to handle the creation of the listbox and the text box.  I attempted to copy the listbox code and modify the code with a 2 to see if adjusting the location of the listbox might make the code function as two listbox windows program.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndList, hwndText;
    int iIndex, iLength, cxChar, cyChar;
    TCHAR* pVarName, * pVarValue;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        cxChar = LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        cyChar = HIWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        // Create listbox and static text windows.
        hwndList = CreateWindow(TEXT("listbox"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD,
            cxChar, cyChar * 3,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 5,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        hwndText = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
            cxChar, cyChar,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), cyChar,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_TEXT,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        FillListBox(hwndList);
        return 0;
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SetFocus(hwndList);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_LIST && HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_SELCHANGE)
        {
            // Get current selection.
            iIndex = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            iLength = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXTLEN, iIndex, 0) + 1;
            pVarName = (TCHAR*)(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXT, iIndex, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            // Get environment string.
            iLength = GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, NULL, 0);
            pVarValue = (TCHAR *) (calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, pVarValue, iLength);
            // Show it in window.
            SetWindowText(hwndText, pVarValue);
            free(pVarName);
            free(pVarValue);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Telling people what you tried without showing them how you you tried leaves us to guess what you might have done wrong, which is any number of things. Show us the actual code you tried and be specific about what doesn't work.

Comment: OK.  I am new to GUI development and despite looking at books and inspecting Microsoft Windows development webpage, it is difficult to breakdown the code to understand what each code does.  By asking the question of a known complete code, I hoped to better understand what each of these codes do.  Now If I was more familiar with GUI development then I would have made myself to ask better questions. I hope this website is not just for experienced programmers.  I imagine as my experience grows in GUI development in Windows, my questions will accompany what I have tried.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I found the plans for a house and I wanted to add a second story. So I built the house and then copied the plans and built a second story on top but it fell down. I don't know much about house building so I can't be more specific than that sorry. Can you please tell me what went wrong with the second story?

Comment: It seems the first floor was built to be a single story.  And the added weight of the second story caused the first story to collapse causing the second story to fall down.

Answer (score 0):

I added a new `ID_NEWLIST` to your source code and created a listbox in the same way.

Here is the sample:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define ID_LIST 1
#define ID_TEXT 2
#define ID_NEWLIST 3
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void FillListBox(HWND hwndList)
{
    int iLength;

    TCHAR* pVarBlock, * pVarBeg, * pVarEnd, * pVarName;

    TCHAR* pVarBlockCopy = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
    pVarBlock = GetEnvironmentStrings(); // Get pointer to environment block
    while (*pVarBlock)
    {
        if (*pVarBlock != '=') // Skip variable names beginning with `=`
        {
            pVarBeg = pVarBlock; // Beginning of variable name
            while (*pVarBlock++ != '='); // Scan until `=`
            pVarEnd = pVarBlock - 1; // Points to `=` sign
            iLength = pVarEnd - pVarBeg; // Length of variable name
            // Allocate memory for the variable name and terminating
            // zero. Copy the variable name and append a zero.
            pVarName = (TCHAR*)(calloc(iLength + 1, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            CopyMemory(pVarName, pVarBeg, iLength * sizeof(TCHAR));
            pVarName[iLength] = '\0';
            // Put the variable name in the list box and free memory.
            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            free(pVarName);
        }
        while (*pVarBlock++ != '\0'); // Scan until terminating zero
    }
    FreeEnvironmentStrings(pVarBlockCopy);
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("Environ");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Environment List Box"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndList, hwndText, hwndNewList;
    int iIndex, iLength, cxChar, cyChar;
    TCHAR* pVarName, * pVarValue;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        cxChar = LOWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        cyChar = HIWORD(GetDialogBaseUnits());
        // Create listbox and static text windows.
        hwndList = CreateWindow(TEXT("listbox"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD,
            cxChar, cyChar * 3,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 5,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_LIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        hwndNewList = CreateWindow(TEXT("listbox"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD,
            cxChar, cyChar * 8,
            cxChar * 16 + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL),
            cyChar * 5,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_NEWLIST,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        hwndText = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,
            cxChar, cyChar,
            GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), cyChar,
            hwnd, (HMENU)ID_TEXT,
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);
        FillListBox(hwndList);
        FillListBox(hwndNewList);
        return 0;
    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        SetFocus(hwndList);
        return 0;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_LIST && HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_SELCHANGE)
        {
            // Get current selection.
            iIndex = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
            iLength = SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXTLEN, iIndex, 0) + 1;
            pVarName = (TCHAR*)(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXT, iIndex, (LPARAM)pVarName);
            // Get environment string.
            iLength = GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, NULL, 0);
            pVarValue = (TCHAR*)(calloc(iLength, sizeof(TCHAR)));
            GetEnvironmentVariable(pVarName, pVarValue, iLength);
            // Show it in window.
            SetWindowText(hwndText, pVarValue);
            free(pVarName);
            free(pVarValue);
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

If you encounter other problems during the creation, I hope you can further point them out so that we can solve them for you.

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.